# Problem installing qt5-default on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, qt5, ubuntu-22.04

I get the following error when installing qt5-defualt on ubuntu 22.04.

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package qt5-default is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'qt5-default' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: The answer is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335184/qt5-default-not-in-ubuntu-21-04

Answer (score 18):

Ubuntu 22.04 repository dont have qt5-default package.

You can get pre-built libraries by installing the qtbase5-dev.

```
sudo apt install qtbase5-dev qt5-qmake
```

Comment: Tanks, I did this but it still gives the same error.

Comment: This works for me. I'm on `Ubuntu 22.04`. Thank you.

Comment: Just to get clarification:  does qtbase5-dev obviate installing qt5-default?

Comment: I installed the packages, but the original package is still not installable, requiring qt5-default.